# Chern classes of restrictions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a vector bundle on some complex projective variety $X$ and let $D\subseteq X$ be a divisor.
Is there any nice description of the Chern classes $c_i(\mathcal{F}\vert_D)$ of the restriction $\mathcal{F}\vert_D$ of $\mathcal{F}$ as elements of the Chow ring of $D$ in terms of the Chern classes of $\mathcal{F}$, $D$ and the inclusion map $i:D\hookrightarrow X$?

This might be a completely trivial question, but at the moment I am completely confused about the appearing notions, so any help would be appreciated.